# Key for encryption/decryption works differently when directly used in code vs when stored in custom setting

Tags: error, encryption, crypto

I am encrypting a message using  Crypto class methods. I have created a key as follows:

```
Blob cryptoKeyBlob = Crypto.generateAesKey(128);
String cryptoKeyString = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(cryptoKeyBlob);
```

I have stored this key in a custom setting. For encryption, I do the following:

```
Blob cryptoKeyBlob = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(setting.Crypto_Key__c);
Blob msgBlob = Blob.valueOf('my message to be encrypted');
Blob encryptedMsgBlob = Crypto.encryptWithManagedIV('AES128', cryptoKeyBlob, msgBlob);
String encryptedMsgString = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(encryptedMsgBlob);
```

The decryption is done as follows:

```
Blob cryptoKeyBlob = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(setting.Crypto_Key__c);
Blob encryptedMsgBlob = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(encryptedMsgString);
Blob decryptedMsgBlob = Crypto.decryptWithManagedIV('AES128', cryptoKeyBlob, encryptedMsgBlob);
String decryptedMsgString = decryptedMsgBlob.toString();
```

However during the decryption, it shows an error saying: **Input length must be multiple of 16 when decrypting with padded cipher**

When I check the debug logs the key Blob is 16 bit i.e. Blob[16]. Isn't 16 a multiple of 16?
If I hard code the key string in the encryption and decryption process it works. I do not understand what am I doing wrong.

Any help will be appreciated.